# Roll a dice, probability that game goes beyond one round

Tags: probability, dice

> There are two people $A$ and $B$. Person $A$ has $8$ chips, and person $B$ has $6$ chips. Each round, both people roll a die then take that number of chips from the other person. The game ends when one person has more chips than the other.
>
> Question 1) What is the probability that the game goes beyond one round?
>
> Question 2) What is a general formula for the probability that the game ends in round $n$?

My answer for (1) is $5/36$. There are five ways to continue the game (a tie):
$$A1B2 \qquad A2B3 \qquad A3B4 \qquad A4B5 \qquad A5B6$$

I didn't figure out (2). Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Generally, you should edit your original question instead of deleting and reposting ([your original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1332259/264)). However, you have demonstrated some improvement so I suppose it's okay.

Comment: The game ends when one has more chips than the other? Then shouldn't the game already ends before it begins, since A has more chips than B?

Answer (score 1):

The answer for 2nd part should be: $$ \frac{31}{36} \times \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^{n-2} \times \frac{5}{6}$$
As after first round, both of them should get same no. until (n-1) round

Comment: Why 1/9 and 8/9 rather than 1/6 and 5/6?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

We have players $A$ and $B$ with some fair dice $D_A=\{1,...,a\}$ and $D_B=\{1,...,b\}$ (i.e. uniform probability for any atomic event $\Pr(D=x)=\frac{1}{|D|}\ $) with number of sides $|D_A|=a$ and $|D_B|=b$ respectively.

Each player have some score that I will name $sA$ and $sB$ where the important thing is the difference between them i.e. $S=sA-sB$.

And we have that for any situation that compare the rolls

$$\Pr(D_A\ \mathbf R\ D_B)=\sum_{D_A=1}^{a}\frac{1}{a}\sum_{D_B=1}^{b}\frac{1}{b}[D_A\ \mathbf R\ D_B]=\frac{1}{ab}\sum_{D_A=1}^{a}\sum_{D_B=1}^{b}[D_A\ \mathbf R\ D_B]$$

for any kind of relation of comparison $\mathbf R$ where the brackets are [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

For any turn exists three different outcomes: $S>0$ where player *A* wins and the game ends, $S=0$ where is a tie and game continue, or $S<0$ where player *B* wins and game ends (I understand that these conditions are for all game but $S_0$, see below).

We start with $S_0=2$, the value of $S$ changes depending on the difference between the rolls of both players i.e. $S_{n+1}=S_n+2(D_A-D_B)_n$.

If the dice have equal number of sides $|D|=m$ we can simplify the above expression as

$$\Pr(D_A\ \mathbf R\ D_B)=\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{1\le D_A,D_B\le m}[D_A\ \mathbf R\ D_B]$$

Because the game have 3 possible outcomes we have 3 different possible conditions:

$$A\ \text{wins} \iff D_A - S/2 > D_B\\ B\ \text{wins} \iff D_A - S/2 < D_B\\ \text{Tie} \iff D_A - S/2= D_B $$

and in any case $S_{n\ne0}/2=0$ and $S_0/2=1$, in other cases the game ends and we dont need take care about any value of $S/2$ anymore :)

Go to probabilities. For the first game we have:

$$\Pr_{n=1}(D_A -1< D_B)=\frac{m+1}{2m}\\
\Pr_{n=1}(D_A -1> D_B)=\frac{(m-2)^\overline{2}}{2m^2}\\
\Pr_{n=1}(D_A -1= D_B)=\frac{m-1}{m^2}$$

where $c^\overline{k}$ denotes the rising factorial. If the game continues then:

$$\Pr_{n>1}(D_A < D_B)=\Pr_{n>1}(D_A > D_B)=\frac{m-1}{2m}\\
\Pr_{n>1}(D_A = D_B)=\frac{1}{m}$$

> Notice that in any turn the probabilities $\sum\Pr(X=x)=1$

The probabilities that game ends in the turn *n* is the probability that it doesnt on $n-1$ turns and it does just in the $n$th turn. Fixing the case for *n=1* will have that the probability that game ends exactly in the turn *n* will be

$$\Pr(N=n)=\frac{(m-1)^2+m[n=1]}{m^{n+1}}$$

If we are using a standard dice with $m=6$ then

$$\Pr(N=n)=\frac{25+6[n=1]}{6^{n+1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first part is ${5 \over 36}$ not ${31 \over 36}$. You're counting the number of ties divided by the number of outcomes.

For the second part, you need the following things to all happen:

1. Round $1$ is a tie.
2. Rounds $2$ to $n-1$ are ties.
3. Round $n$ is *not* a tie.

The probability of 1 is ${5 \over 36}$.
For 2, the outcomes in each round must be one of $A1B1$, $A2B2$ to $A6B6$. The probability of that happening in a single round is ${6 \over 36} = {1 \over 6}$, and for $n-2$ rounds ${1 \over 6^{n-2}}$.
The probability of round $n$ being the last one is $1 - $ the probability of a tie. That's ${5 \over 6}$.

Of course, each of these events is independent so you multiply to get $${5 \times 6 \over 36} \cdot{1 \over 6^{n-2}}$$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have corrected the first part.

Comment: For the probability of round n being the last one, is that 30/36=5/6 rather than 31/36? since round n-1 is still a tie.

Comment: @nunu Yes. Good point.